# How to block window.showModalDialog popups from a BHO?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, popup, bho, showmodaldialog

I am working on a BHO popups / ads blocker, and I can't find how to block this js triggered popup:

```
var popDialogOptions = "dialogWidth:795px; dialogHeight:500px; center:1; menubar:1; tollbar:1; location:0; resizable:1; scroll:1; status:1; fullscreen;yes";
eval("window.showModalDialog('http://uri.com/popup.html,'',popDialogOptions)");
```

I am intercepting DISPID_NEWWINDOW, DISPID_NEWWINDOW2 and DISPID_NEWWINDOW3 but none of those are being fired, but the popup does open.

**How could I block this type of popups?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with IE BHOs, however, regarding JavaScript itself: have you considered adding at the beginning of the page

`window.showModalDialog = new Function();`

e.g. by inserting new `<script>` as a first child of `<head>` (prevents popup for me in IE8/XP) or this is too brutal (because it blocks modal dialogs at all)?